# Unable to get an image in the output when using MNIST Database using Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, matplotlib-basemap

iter_test = 0

for images, labels in test_loader:

```
iter_test += 1

images = images.view(-1, 28*28)

outputs = model(images)
_, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)

if iter_test == 1:
    print('PREDICTION')
    print(predicted[0])

    print('LABEL SIZE')
    print(labels.size())

    print('LABEL FOR IMAGE 0')
    print(labels[0])
```

I get the output of this code as follows:

> > PREDICTION
> >
> > tensor(7)
> >
> > LABEL SIZE
> >
> > torch.Size([100])
> >
> > LABEL FOR IMAGE 0
> >
> > tensor(7)

The code works perfectly. I was wondering if i could get the "MNIST" like image as output along with prediction?

Comment: That is part of your test data set. You can always show the actual value and actual image from test loader. Do you want your network to generate an "MNIST" like image as output along with prediction?

Comment: Yeah, but unable to understand how

Comment: Which network are you using? There are networks that can generate images, but it depends on your use case. For starters, you can read https://blog.openai.com/generative-models/.

Comment: I am using the MNIST network (bunch of numbers as images). I was thinking to get the output using matploitlib

Comment: That bunch of number images is called data set (training, validation & test). But that data set is fed to a network during training, validation or testing phases. Network is the one that is predicting the numerical value from digit images. Are you following tutorial from tensorflow website? pyplot is for showing existing images like the ones from data set and other drawing tasks like drawing graphs. But pyplot does not "generate" images.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I realized that i have created and trained a dataset. Now when testing i was wondering if pyplot could show me the existing actual image and i can compare that to to the predicted value.

Comment: Yes :). You can use pyplot and show the image loaded by test_loader. Check https://www.oreilly.com/learning/not-another-mnist-tutorial-with-tensorflow . Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes :).

You can use pyplot and show the image loaded by test_loader.

Check https://www.oreilly.com/learning/not-another-mnist-tutorial-with-tensorflow .

Hope this helps!